# Set NotifyOnSourceUpdate for Image in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is it possible to set `NotifyOnSourceUpdate` property in code behind for `Image` in `WPF`? I need to do this in code behind. I can't use: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyonsourceupdated.aspx)

Comment: is your binding already set in xaml and you want to change from code behind, or do you want to create the whole binding in code behind?

Comment: Nope, it isn't. The new item doesn't exist in `XAML`. It's being created while app is running and doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Binding` has already been set in `Xaml` or code you cannot change the Binding properties, but you can just create and assign a new binding to your `Image`

```
 Binding binding = new Binding("MyImageProperty") { NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true };
 image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, binding);
```